# aspnet drop down validation issue (Validation works only after toggling options)

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, validation

I have a drop down list in my aspx page with 3 values

```
1.Please Select... ( Values as "0")
2 XYZ  (some text value)
3 ABC  (some text value)
```

"Please Select" is the option that is selected by default.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="therapyTypeDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="RequiredTextField" > 
 </asp:DropDownList>

   //Validation
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  InitialValue="0" ID="valTherapyType"  
  Display="None" ValidationGroup="formPat" runat="server"  
  ControlToValidate="therapyTypeDropDown" SetFocusOnError="True" 
  ErrorMessage="Therapy Type is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When I load the page and click on Submit , the validation error message is not thrown.
But if I go and toggle with the options e.g( select option 2 and then option 1) and then click on submit , the validation is triggered and the  error message is displayed.

I need the validation to work without having to toggle with my drop down options.

**EDIT:**
Usage of drop down in code

```
 ListItem oItemTherapy = new ListItem(); 
 oItemTherapy.Value = "0"; 
 oItemTherapy.Text = "Please select a type...";
 therapyTypeDropDown.Items.Insert(0, oItemTherapy); 
 //(setting the 0th index as selected) 
 ((DropDownList)tblWounds.FindControl("therapyTypeDropDown")).SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: My problem isn't with adding a RequiredField Validator. If you  observe I have already used the Intiial Value attribute by setting it to 0 so that validation is triggered.

My issue is that the validation is ONLY triggered when I toggle the options.

Comment: Hi, just a few things to double check. Is this in an update panel? When the page loads the value of the default selction is definately 0? Some code behind usage of where your using this might also be quite helpful

Comment: Actually this is an Insert Panel. The update panel refers to this very same aspx page and its drop down validation works fine.
Coming to your second question,below is my code behind usage where I set the "0" index of the drop down as selected
(inserting element at 0th postion)

ListItem oItemTherapy = new ListItem();
            oItemTherapy.Value = "0";
            oItemTherapy.Text = "Please select a type...";
            therapyTypeDropDown.Items.Insert(0, oItemTherapy);

  (setting the 0th index as selected)
((DropDownList)tblWounds.FindControl("therapyTypeDropDown")).SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Is this logic in the page load?

Comment: Yes this is in Page Load

Comment: Are you able to provide your submit method?